# Как обновить datalist option с помощью ajax

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, json, datalist

С помощью jQuery пытаюсь обновить `option` в `datalist`

`response = {'is_taken': [{'id': 3, 'name': 'Casio'}, {'id': 5, 'name': 'Casio Edifice'}, {'id': 6, 'name': 'Casio G-Shock'}], 'is_exist': True}`

**как перебрать в `list` в `is_taken`, чтобы обновить данные в datalist?**

это `jsonOptions.forEach(function(response.is_taken)` выдает ошибку `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'`

**html**

```
    $('#ajax_input').keyup(function () {
        // create an AJAX call
        $.ajax({
            data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
            url: "{% url 'ajax_request' %}?model=device",
            // on success
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.is_exist == true) {
                    console.log('is_exist = true')
                    $("#ajax-one_form-device").text(response.is_taken.name);
                    vardataList = document.getElementById('{{ widget.name }}');
                    var input = document.getElementById('ajax_input_{{ widget.name }}');


                    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    // Обрабатываем изменение состояния для запроса.
                    // Парсируем JSON
                    // Перебираем через цикл массив JSON.
                    jsonOptions.forEach(function(response.is_taken) {
                            // Создаем новый элемент <option>.
                            var option = document.createElement('option');
                            // Устанавливаем значение, используя элементы массива JSON.
                            option.value = response.is_taken['id'];
                            option.label = response.is_taken['name'];
                            // Добавляем элемент <option> к <datalist>.
                            dataList.appendChild(option);
                          });

                          // Обновляем текст заполнителя.
                    input.placeholder = "e.g. datalist";


                    // Обновляем текст заполнителя.
                    input.placeholder = "Loading options...";

                    // Настраиваем и выполняем запрос.
                    request.open('GET', 'html-elements.json', true);
                    request.send();




                    console.log(vardataList)
                    console.log(input)

                }
                else {
                     $("#ajax-{{ widget.name }}").text('Нет в базе');
                }
            },
            // on error
            error: function (response) {
                // alert the error if any error occured
                console.log(response.responseJSON.errors)
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: forEach принимает callback, вы указываете что параметром callback функции будет ```response.is_taken```, это не правильно, укажите просто ```response```

Comment: Точнее еще правильнее будет: ```request.is_taken.forEach(function(response)```. А внутри использовать уже ```response.id``` ```response.name```.

Comment: спасибо, сработало, можете добавить в ответ, я галку поставлю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неизвестно что за переменная `jsonOptions`, возможно опечатка.
Ошибка заключалась в том, что вы указывали в параметре функции как я понял свойство объекта которое я так понимаю вы хотели передать в функцию. Но на самом деле мы создаем фкнкцию и указываем "внутреннее" имя переменной. Не знаю как более правильно обьяснить. В данной переменной будет элемент массива на итерации "цикла", назвать эту перепенную мы можем как угодно, она служит для работы внутри "цикла". По этому правильная строка будет:
`request.is_taken.forEach(function(response)`